# Session variable behaves differently between browsers

Tags: php, session

I'm dealing with very odd behaviour between different browsers and even the same browser on different systems. I have a form that gets processed and sends a mail. To avoid sending the same mail again after refresh a session variable is checked.

For some reason Firefox on my system unsets the variable even if the surrounding `if` is not true. This doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox on another system. And as far as I understand PHP shouldn't be browser dependent at all.

```
echo '<p>$_SESSION: <br />';
var_dump($_SESSION); //for testing only
echo '</p>'; 

if(!isset($_POST['csent'])): 
    unset($_SESSION['call-sent']); // to reenable the form for a different message
?>

    <form id="call-form" action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="csent" value="1">
        ...
    </form>

<?php elseif( ( isset($_POST['csent']) ) 
              && ( !isset($_SESSION['call-sent']) ) ):

    $_SESSION['call-sent'] = 'x';

      /*all the stuff that handels the form*/
?>

    <div id="formsent">
        <!-- Success Message -->
    </div>

<?php else: ?> 
    <div id="formsent" class="repeat">
        <!-- Success Message -->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In my FF `var_dump($_SESSION)` is always `array(0) { }`. The form though is only displayed before it has been send. If I comment the unset out the dump is `array(1) { ["call-sent"]=> string(1) "x" }` as expected.

In Chrome it is `array(1) { ["call-sent"]=> string(1) "x" }` after the form has been send and the page reloaded.

This is part of a wordpress template should it matter.

Comment: Do you block cookies on one system, but not the other?

Comment: There are differences between the systems but it's the FF that is less restrictive regarding cookies that doesn't behave as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should redirect to another page, once you've processed your POST data. That way the user cannot refresh the page.

Simply put `header('Location: http://yoursite.com/path/to/script.php'); die();` after your POST processing.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid that as the form is in a sidebar rather than on a dedicated page. I'll keep it in mind though.